# Apache Tomcat 7, ant list = BUILD FAILED

Tags: list, ant, tomcat7

For the simple MVC springapp, I am trying to deploy the web app. 
"ant" and "ant deploywar" build commands work fine. It gives error when doing "ant list"

Here is the build.properties

```
appserver.home=/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.47
appserver.lib=${appserver.home}/lib

deploy.path=${appserver.home}/webapps

tomcat.manager.url=http://localhost:8080/manager
tomcat.manager.username=tomcat
tomcat.manager.password=s3cret
```

Here is the part related to list in build.xml

```
<target name="list" description="List Tomcat applications">
    <list url="${tomcat.manager.url}"
             username="${tomcat.manager.username}"
             password="${tomcat.manager.password}"/>
</target>
```

The manager is working in the browser and I can browse the list of applications as well

```
OK: http://localhost:8080
OK: http://localhost:8080/manager
OK: http://localhost:8080/manager/html
OK: http://localhost:8080/manager/html/list
```

and when I go to ListApplications from the HTML interface of manager, it goes to

```
http://localhost:8080/manager/html/list?org.apache.catalina.filters.CSRF_NONCE=BFCB46A8A1735E7DA7FBE4033D6BEC2D
```

which is fine. But when I do "ant list" via terminal from the root directory of my app, it gives this error,

```
Buildfile: /Users/saad/Development/springapp/build.xml

list:

BUILD FAILED
/Users/saad/Development/springapp/build.xml:144: java.io.FileNotFoundException:     http://localhost:8080/manager/list
at     sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1624)
at org.apache.catalina.ant.AbstractCatalinaTask.execute(AbstractCatalinaTask.java:230)
at org.apache.catalina.ant.AbstractCatalinaTask.execute(AbstractCatalinaTask.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.ant.ListTask.execute(ListTask.java:51)
at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:809)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:217)
at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)

Total time: 0 seconds
```

When I changed the url in build.properties to

```
tomcat.manager.url=http://localhost:8080/manager/html
```

It returns the whole html page of the manager on doing "ant list".

or if

```
tomcat.manager.url=http://localhost:8080/manager/text
```

It gives the error:

```
 /Users/saad/Development/springapp/build.xml:144: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://localhost:8080/manager/text/list
```

Comment: FYI. I just resolved it on my way to post this question. I better share the problem/solution for someone else. The missing link was adding a role of "manager-script" in tomcat/conf/tomcat-users.xml

Answer (score 4):

Its a change from tomcat 6 to tomcat 7. Use ':8080/manager/text' instead of ':8080/manager/' in the tomcat.manager.url in build properties.

Answer (score 2):

```
I had the same issue. I fixed it by following the below procedure.

It worked for me by changing tomcat.manager.url='http://apache.host123.com:8080/manager/' to
tomcat.manager.url='http://apache.host123.com:8080/manager/text' in build.properties. 

My build.xml is below:

<?xml version="1.0"?>

<project name="springapp" basedir="." default="usage">
    <property file="build.properties"/>

    <property name="src.dir" value="src"/>
    <property name="web.dir" value="war"/>
    <property name="build.dir" value="${web.dir}/WEB-INF/classes"/>
    <property name="name" value="springapp"/>

    <path id="master-classpath">
        <fileset dir="${web.dir}/WEB-INF/lib">
            <include name="*.jar"/>
        </fileset>
        <!-- We need the servlet API classes: -->
        <!--  * for Tomcat 5/6 use servlet-api.jar -->
        <!--  * for other app servers - check the docs -->
        <fileset dir="${appserver.lib}">
            <include name="servlet*.jar"/>
        </fileset>
        <pathelement path="${build.dir}"/>
    </path>

    <target name="usage">
        <echo message=""/>
        <echo message="${name} build file"/>
        <echo message="-----------------------------------"/>
        <echo message=""/>
        <echo message="Available targets are:"/>
        <echo message=""/>
        <echo message="build     --> Build the application"/>
        <echo message="deploy    --> Deploy application as directory"/>
        <echo message="deploywar --> Deploy application as a WAR file"/>
        <echo message="install   --> Install application in Tomcat"/>
        <echo message="reload    --> Reload application in Tomcat"/>
        <echo message="start     --> Start Tomcat application"/>
        <echo message="stop      --> Stop Tomcat application"/>
        <echo message="list      --> List Tomcat applications"/>
        <echo message=""/>
    </target>

    <target name="build" description="Compile main source tree java files">
        <mkdir dir="${build.dir}"/>
        <javac destdir="${build.dir}" source="1.5" target="1.5" debug="true"
               deprecation="false" optimize="false" failonerror="true">
            <src path="${src.dir}"/>
            <classpath refid="master-classpath"/>
        </javac>
    </target>

    <target name="deploy" depends="build" description="Deploy application">
        <copy todir="${deploy.path}/${name}" preservelastmodified="true">
            <fileset dir="${web.dir}">
                <include name="**/*.*"/>
            </fileset>
        </copy>
    </target>

    <target name="deploywar" depends="build" description="Deploy application as a WAR file">
        <war destfile="${name}.war"
             webxml="${web.dir}/WEB-INF/web.xml">
            <fileset dir="${web.dir}">
                <include name="**/*.*"/>
            </fileset>
        </war>
        <copy todir="${deploy.path}" preservelastmodified="true">
            <fileset dir=".">
                <include name="*.war"/>
            </fileset>
        </copy>
    </target>

<!-- ============================================================== -->
<!-- Tomcat tasks - remove these if you don't have Tomcat installed -->
<!-- ============================================================== -->

    <path id="catalina-ant-classpath">
        <!-- We need the Catalina jars for Tomcat -->
        <!--  * for other app servers - check the docs -->
        <fileset dir="${appserver.lib}">
            <include name="catalina-ant.jar"/>
            <include name="catalina-ant.jar"/>
            <include name="tomcat-coyote.jar"/>
            <include name="tomcat-util.jar"/>
        </fileset>
        <fileset dir="${appserver.home}/bin">
                        <include name="tomcat-juli.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </path>

    <taskdef name="install" classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.DeployTask">
        <classpath refid="catalina-ant-classpath"/>
    </taskdef>
    <taskdef name="reload" classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.ReloadTask">
        <classpath refid="catalina-ant-classpath"/>
    </taskdef>
    <taskdef name="list" classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.ListTask">
        <classpath refid="catalina-ant-classpath"/>
    </taskdef>
    <taskdef name="start" classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.StartTask">
        <classpath refid="catalina-ant-classpath"/>
    </taskdef>
    <taskdef name="stop" classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.StopTask">
        <classpath refid="catalina-ant-classpath"/>
    </taskdef>

    <target name="install" description="Install application in Tomcat">
        <install url="${tomcat.manager.url}"
                 username="${tomcat.manager.username}"
                 password="${tomcat.manager.password}"
                 path="/${name}"
                 war="${name}"/>
    </target>

    <target name="reload" description="Reload application in Tomcat">
        <reload url="${tomcat.manager.url}"
                 username="${tomcat.manager.username}"
                 password="${tomcat.manager.password}"
                 path="/${name}"/>
    </target>

    <target name="start" description="Start Tomcat application">
        <start url="${tomcat.manager.url}"
                 username="${tomcat.manager.username}"
                 password="${tomcat.manager.password}"
                 path="/${name}"/>
    </target>

    <target name="stop" description="Stop Tomcat application">
        <stop url="${tomcat.manager.url}"
                 username="${tomcat.manager.username}"
                 password="${tomcat.manager.password}"
                 path="/${name}"/>
    </target>

    <target name="list" description="List Tomcat applications">
        <list url="${tomcat.manager.url}/text"
                 username="${tomcat.manager.username}"
                 password="${tomcat.manager.password}"/>
    </target>

<!-- End Tomcat tasks -->

</project>

My build.properties is below:

# Ant properties for building the springapp

appserver.home=D:/apache-tomcat-7.0.42
# for Tomcat 5 use $appserver.home}/server/lib
# for Tomcat 6 use $appserver.home}/lib
appserver.lib=${appserver.home}/lib

deploy.path=${appserver.home}/webapps

tomcat.manager.url='http://apache.localhost.com:8080/manager/text'
tomcat.manager.username=tomcat
tomcat.manager.password=s3cret

Hope these changes will fix your problem.
```

Answer (score 1):

2 things needed

1) in build.xml

the url has to "${tomcat.manager.url}/text"

```
<target name="list" description="List Tomcat applications">
    <list url="${tomcat.manager.url}/text"
        username="${tomcat.manager.username}"
        password="${tomcat.manager.password}"/>
</target>
```

2) in ${appserver.home}/conf/tomcat-users.xml
the manager should have 'manager-script' one of the roles.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<tomcat-users>
  <role rolename="manager"/>
  <user username="tomcat" password="s3cret" roles="manager,manager-script"/>
</tomcat-users>
```